# Magento sitemap gets cut off

Tags: sitemaps

I have a site with three languages and three sitemaps (one for each language).

Two of the languages have working sitemaps (spanish and arabic), but for some reason the english one gets cut off with the following error message:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: https://firstaidvendor.com/sitemap/first_aid_vendor_english/sitemap.xml
Line Number 2, Column 664358:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a error in your data input.

Checked it, more specific in `advanced-child-airway-management-torso-with-defibrillation-ecg-and-aed`

It has a unsupported char in it. So fix your content and your problem is solved.
I guess it is a category.

Maybe something went wrong copy/pasting.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. There was a weird character in the product name.